# websocket was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websocket

hi guys im trying implement an example of send file through websocket using sendBinary method . I`m deploying server code in Tomcat 8.0.20 and client code using tyrus 1.8.3 implementation/provider .  There are my server and client class :

Server code :

```
package socket;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import javax.websocket.CloseReason;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/chat")
public class Server {


  @OnOpen
  public void onOpen(Session session) {

  }

  @OnClose
  public void onClose(Session session,CloseReason closeReason) {

  }

  @OnError
  public void onError(Throwable throwable){
      throwable.printStackTrace();
  }

  @OnMessage
  public void message(String message, Session session) throws IOException {

  }

  @OnMessage
  public void message(Session session,ByteBuffer byteBuffer) throws IOException {
      System.out.println(" Binary received ... ");
  }
}
```

Client code :

```
package br.com.jslsolucoes.socket.client;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

import javax.websocket.ClientEndpoint;
import javax.websocket.CloseReason;
import javax.websocket.ContainerProvider;
import javax.websocket.DeploymentException;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.WebSocketContainer;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

@ClientEndpoint
public class Client {

    private static CountDownLatch latch;

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                "/myvideo.wmv");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
        while (IOUtils.read(inputStream, buffer) != 0) {
            session.getBasicRemote().sendBinary(ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer));
        }
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session,CloseReason closeReason) throws IOException {
        latch.countDown();
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void processMessage(String message) {

    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable throwable){
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws DeploymentException,
            IOException, InterruptedException {
        latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider
                .getWebSocketContainer();
        String uri = "ws://localhost:8081/socket/chat";
        Client client = new Client();
        container.connectToServer(client, URI.create(uri));
        latch.await();
    }
}
```

its works ok but while uploading after a time about 30 seconds an exception is launched :

```
java.io.ioexception : an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.read(NioChannel.java:140)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.NioServletInputStream.fillReadBuffer(NioServletInputStream.java:136)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.NioServletInputStream.doRead(NioServletInputStream.java:80)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletInputStream.read(AbstractServletInputStream.java:124)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.onDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:51)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler$WsReadListener.onDataAvailable(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:203)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletInputStream.onDataAvailable(AbstractServletInputStream.java:198)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractProcessor.upgradeDispatch(AbstractProcessor.java:96)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:654)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Someone can help me with this problem ?

Comment: Did the server run into a SocketTimeoutException? Or the file to send is to large to be buffered by the server.

Comment: the file size its about 24mb but im sending in parts in the code no ? server launch just that exception not a SocketTimeoutException .